# How to implement std::set or std::hash_set to filter the duplicated item in an array list?

Tags: c++, hash, set

Given the below scenario, I'm having a list of item which might be having some duplicated item. 
I would like to filter the item, to print the only unique item.

Instead of duplicating a list which remove the duplicated item, I tried to insert them into std::set and std::hash_set. Nevertheless, I found no useful example to perform the operation.

Hence I hope to seek your advice on the following code:

```
#include <list>
//--> A struct to store software name and version
typedef struct tagSWVERStruct{
  TCHAR szSWName[255];
  TCHAR szVersion[255];
}SWVERSIONSTRUCT, *LPSWVERSIONSTRUCT;

//--> A list of struct to store software name and version
typedef std::list<SWVERSIONSTRUCT>  LISTSWVERSION, *PLISTSWVERSION;

void main()
{
  LISTSWVERSION swList;
  SWVERSIONSTRUCT svSW1, svSW2, svSW3, svSW4;
  CString szVersion, szName;

  //Assign value
  _tcscpy_s(svSW1.szSWName, _T("Adapter 1"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW2.szSWName, _T("Adapter 2"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW3.szSWName, _T("Adapter 1"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW4.szSWName, _T("Adapter 3"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW1.szVersion, _T("1.0.0"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW2.szVersion, _T("2.0.0"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW3.szVersion, _T("1.0.0"));
  _tcscpy_s(svSW4.szVersion, _T("3.0.0"));
  swList.push_back(svSW1);
  swList.push_back(svSW2);
  swList.push_back(svSW3);
  swList.push_back(svSW4);

  //print all the item out
  LISTSWVERSION::iterator it = swList.begin();
  for(; it!=swList.end(); ++it){    
    _tprintf(_T("%s version = %s\n"), (*it).szSWName, (*it).szVersion);
  }
}

/*******
Output:  
Adapter 1 version = 1.0.0 
Adapter 2 version = 2.0.0 
Adapter 1 version = 1.0.0 
Adapter 3 version = 3.0.0

Expected Output: 
Adapter 1 version = 1.0.0 
Adapter 2 version = 2.0.0 
Adapter 3 version = 3.0.0
********/
```

Comment: eh? you aren't using std::set at all

Comment: replace `std::list` with `std::set` and `push_back` with `insert` and you're good to go. See dauphic's answer.

Comment: **hash_set**: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html  /  
**set**: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing duplicates is easy, assuming you can modify the sequence.

First you will need less-than and equality functors:

```
struct less_SWVERSIONSTRUCT
{
  bool operator () (SWVERSIONSTRUCT const & a, SWVERSIONSTRUCT const & b) const
  {
    // Replace this with the appropriate less-than relation for the structure.
    return std::memcmp (&a, &b, sizeof (a)) < 0;
  }
};

struct eq_SWVERSIONSTRUCT
{
  bool operator () (SWVERSIONSTRUCT const & a, SWVERSIONSTRUCT const & b) const
  {
    // Replace this with the appropriate equality relation for the structure.
    return std::memcmp (&a, &b, sizeof (a)) == 0;
  }
};
```

Then sort the list using the comparator:

```
swList.sort (less_SWVERSIONSTRUCT ());
```

And now remove sequences of duplicate members:

```
swList.erase (
    std::unique (swList.begin (), swList.end (), eq_SWVERSIONSTRUCT ()),
    swList.end ());
```

Done.

Comment: swList.sort(LESS_SWVERSIONSTRUCT());
 swList.unique(EQ_SWVERSIONSTRUCT());

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding, but if you want to copy the elements of an `std::list` into an `std::set`, you can use a `std::copy` with an `inserter`.

```
std::list<int> list;
list.push_back(1);
list.push_back(2);
list.push_back(2);
list.push_back(3);

std::set<int> set;
std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::inserter(set));
```

Comment: This code assumes that the list is already sorted which is not the case with the input provided in the question.

Comment: This should be `std::inserter(set, set.end())` (the iterator doesn't matter for `set::insert()` correctness, it's just a performance hint; end() works better if the data is sorted).  Alas, this doesn't work for hash_set because `hash_set::insert()` doesn't take a 2nd where-to-insert iterator param.